# find all items where a list field contains a value in dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to DynamoDb and I'm struggling to work out how to do this (using the java sdk).

I currently have a table (in mongo) for notifications.  The schema is basically as follows (I've simplified it)

```
id: string
notifiedUsers: [123, 345, 456, 567]
message: "this is a message"
created: 12345678000 (epoch millis)
```

I wanted to migrate to Dynamodb, but I can't work out the best way to select all notifications that went to a particular user after a certain date?

I gather I can't have an index on a list like notifiedUsers, therefore I can't use a query in this case - is that correct?

I'd prefer not to scan and then filter, there could be a lot of records.

Is there a way to do this using a query or another approach?

EDIT
This is what I'm trying now, it's not working and I'm not sure where to take it (if anywhere).

```
Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.CONTAINS.toString())
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(userId));

if(startTimestamp != null) {
  rangeKeyCondition = rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT.toString())
      .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(startTimestamp));
}

NotificationFeedDynamoRecord replyKey = new NotificationFeedDynamoRecord();
replyKey.setId(partitionKey);

DynamoDBQueryExpression<NotificationFeedDynamoRecord> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<NotificationFeedDynamoRecord>()
    .withHashKeyValues(replyKey)
    .withRangeKeyCondition(NOTIFICATIONS, rangeKeyCondition);
```

Comment: Have you considered changing the schema or is that not allowed?

Comment: it's allowed but I haven't found a good alternative.  I've simplified the schema for the question, however the actual table has a hidden list, a readTimestamp map and other things. If I can make it work it would be easier but I take your point.

Comment: DynamoDB encourages the usage of "A composite hash-range key is indexed as a hash key element and a range key element. This multi-part key maintains a hierarchy between the first and second element values. For example, a composite hash-range key could be a combination of “UserID” (hash) and “Timestamp” (range). Holding the hash key element constant, you can search across the range key element to retrieve items. This would allow you to use the Query API to, for example, retrieve all items for a single UserID across a range of timestamps."

Comment: Sounds like you would have to change the schema such that each notification represents one specific user's notification so that you can do userID + timestamp hash-range key. This would probably mean data duplication compared to your current mongodb scheme.

Comment: yep, I'm coming to that view myself.  you get a lot more records, but less mess, that or we stick with mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this question, in the end we flattened the schema, so that there is now a record per userId.  This has lead to problems because it's not possible with dynamoDb to atomically batch write records.  With the original schema we had one record, and could write it atomically ensuring that all users got that notification.  Now we cannot be certain, and this is causing pain.

Comment: 5 Years later, have you found any better and more efficient approach?